# Search in CCSprite array element Objective C (cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d and I want to see if a specific string is in the array's element. Here is the element, which is a CCSprite object:

```
<theSwift = 08A6EA70 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,27.00,75.00) | tag = 2 | atlasIndex = -1>
```

I am spawning "monsters" and one type of monsters get the tag = 1 and some get the tag = 2. Is it possible to check if the last monster spawned got the tag = 2 in the element above?

Comment: Is this using cocos2d? If so, you can use `getChildByTag:` methinks.

Comment: Youre right Richard iam! Thank you for that answer ill go check that right this minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that object is in an array, you could use an [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to find the object with a certain tag:

```
NSArray *myArray;

NSObject childWithTag = [[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == 2"]]] lastObject];
```

EDIT: Since you are using cocos2d, its as simple as this:

```
CCSprite *spriteWithTag = (CCSprite *)[myLayer childWithTag:2];
```

Comment: Ok, now why down vote? This answer works perfectly well, doesn't it?

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? Its not that yours is better. Better downvote the question as it hasn't got enough detail

Comment: @Maxner thats a low blow bro. I down voted your answer because it was incorrect, not because it was a bad answer. My answer is not incorrect, so you shouldn't be down voting it. Besides, when was the last time you saw an NSPredicate used?

Comment: I dont have the rep to down vote so it was not me who did that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, I'll give it a shot though:

If the line above is simply an `NSString` and all you want is to check for `tag = 2`, then you'd do:

```
NSRange range = [theString rangeOfString:@"tag = 2"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // theString contains "tag = 2"
}
```

Comment: Just a warning though, this will also find `tag = 20`, `tag = 21`, etc. The best way to do it if that line is a string would be to parse it into either a dictionary or an actual object.

Comment: @cobbal: You're absolutely correct. I'd use a class to represent these things instead of plain strings anyways...

Comment: I don't think that his line is actually an `NSString`, but more likely the debug output of a `CCSprite` subclass in cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about NSArray, then do this:

You can use `containsObject` in an if statement:

```
if ([array containsObject:@"tag = 2"]) {
    //contains tag = 2
}
```

It would be better to use NSDictionary though. Use `setObject:forKey:` in NSMutableDictionary to set the values for their keys, and to check the value do:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"tag"]
```

I would recommend using the NSDictionary method.

Comment: That won't work, look at his output, the array contains a number of those `CCSprite` objects, the array doesn't contain `NSString`s. However, if you changed that to use an `NSPredicate` (like my answer) you could use 'tag == 2'.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII He didn't say that its not an NSArray... No need to down vote!?

Comment: Thats right, he is using an NSArray, but the NSArray is filled with CCSprite Objects, not NSStrings...

Comment: Also, its recommended to use setObject:forKey with NSDictionaries, as setValue:forKey: is for KVC, not dictionaries.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII he didn't say anything of CCSprite. My answer works perfectly for nsstrings so i don't see a point in down voting it, .

Comment: Just chill out bro, if you read the OP's comments, you will see that he is using CCSprite, Not NSString...

Comment: And now that I read your answer again, it wouldn't work even if the objects were NSStrings, as the object the array is not just 'tag = 2', but the whole output of the CCSprite.

Comment: I answered before the comments were added. I don't get people that randomly down vote answers, are the trolls now even on SO? Isn't youtube enough for them?

Comment: Lets just stop, OK? This is stupid to continue this argument. If you are calling me a troll, do you think a troll around here could get 4.5k rep? No. So I will now leave you and your answer alone.

Comment: @Maxner: Please, a down-vote is not the end of the world and certainly no reason to start name-calling. It simply means someone disagrees with you and that's absolutely normal here. Also, since you can't see *who* down-voted you it's not a good idea to start accusations without someone admitting to have down-voted you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this method

```
  [layerName getChildByTag:<(NSInteger)>]
```

for getting the child of any layer.